# MATLAB's imfinfo in openCV

Tags: c++, opencv

MATLAB has a nice function [imfinfo](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imfinfo.html) from which I can know image dimensions without really loading it. Is there a similar function in openCV (C++)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no similar method. You have to access each property and create own string/structure.